# Error saying that an object is a NoneType?

Tags: python

So I am writing a program for Python where a "User" object is created and manipulated.

I have a Linked List of objects with the Nodes representing `User` objects.

When I set a variable `x` as a User object, by searching through the list and setting the variable equal to the returned Node data, (for example `x = List.search("a username")` where `search` returns the User object with the searched name) I get a `User` object (verified using `type(x)`)

However I get a NoneType error when attempting to use methods from the `User` class on this `x` variable.

What could be causing this?
It works when `x` is assigned to `User` object directly (i.e. `x = User()`) but doesn't work in the former case.

---

Notes for code: Takes in commands from a .txt file, these commands being "Add" and "Friend" among others. Friend is supposed to add each User object to a LinkedList in another User object and vice versa

Code:

```
class Node (object):

   def __init__(self,initdata):
      self.data = initdata
      self.next = None            # always do this â€“ saves a lot
                                  # of headaches later!
   def getData (self):
      return self.data            # returns a POINTER

   def getNext (self):
      return self.next            # returns a POINTER

   def setData (self, newData):
      self.data = newData         # changes a POINTER

   def setNext (self,newNext):
      self.next = newNext         # changes a POINTER

class UnorderedList ():

   def __init__(self):
      self.head = None

   def isEmpty (self):
      return self.head == None

   def add (self,item):
      # add a new Node to the beginning of an existing list
      temp = Node(item)
      temp.setNext(self.head)
      self.head = temp

   def length (self):
      current = self.head
      count = 0

      while current != None:
         count += 1
         current = current.getNext()

      return count

   def search (self,item): #NOW RETURNS OBJECT IN LIST
      current = self.head

      while current != None:
         if current.getData().name == item:
             return current.getData()
         else:
            current = current.getNext()

      return None

   def remove (self,item):
      current = self.head
      previous = None
      found = False

      while not found:
         if current.getData() == item:
            found = True
         else:
            previous = current
            current = current.getNext()

      if previous == None:
         self.head = current.getNext()
      else:
         previous.setNext(current.getNext() )

class User():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.friendsList = UnorderedList()

    def setName(self,info):
        self.name = info

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def removeFriend(self, item):
        self.friendsList.remove(item)

    def addFriend(self, item):
        self.friendsList.add(item)

    def searchList(self, item):
        self.friendsList.search(item)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

def main():

    inFile = open("FriendData.txt")
    peopleList = UnorderedList()

    for line in inFile:
        textList = line.split()

        if "Person" in textList:

            newUser = User()
            newUser.setName(textList[1])

            if peopleList.search(newUser.getName()) != None:
                print("This user is already in the program")

            else:
                peopleList.add(newUser)
                print(newUser.getName(),"now has an account")

        elif "Friend" in textList:
            #PROBLEM OBJECTS a AND b BELOW
            a = peopleList.search(textList[1]) #returns user1 object
            b = peopleList.search(textList[2]) # return user2 object
            b.getName()


            if peopleList.search(textList[1]) == None:
                print("A person with the name", textList[1], "does not currently exist")
            elif peopleList.search(textList[2]) == None:
                print("A person with the name", textList[2], "does not currently exist")
            elif textList[1]==textList[2]:
                print("A person cannot friend him/herself")
            elif peopleList.search(textList[1]).searchList(textList[2])!= None:
                print(textList[1],"and",textList[2],"are already friends")
            elif peopleList.search(textList[2]).searchList(textList[1]) != None:
                print(textList[2],"and",textList[1],"are already friends")
            #else:
                #a.friendsList.add(b) #adds user 2 to user1 friendlist
                #b.addFriend(a)
                #print(a.getName(),"and",b.getName(),"are now friends")

main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rsaen/Desktop/Python Prgms/Friends.py", line 137, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/rsaen/Desktop/Python Prgms/Friends.py", line 119, in main
    b.getName()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getName'
```

Parsed .txt file

```
['Person', 'Rachel']
['Person', 'Monica']
['Friend', 'Rachel', 'Monica']
['Friend', 'Monica', 'Rachel']
['Friend', 'Rachel', 'Ross']
['Person', 'Ross']
['Friend', 'Rachel', 'Ross']
['Person', 'Joey']
['Person', 'Joey']
['Friend', 'Joey', 'Joey']
['Friend', 'Joey', 'Rachel']
['Person', 'Chandler']
['Friend', 'Chandler', 'Monica']
['Friend', 'Chandler', 'Rachel']
['Friend', 'Ross', 'Chandler']
['Friend', 'Phoebe', 'Rachel']
['Person', 'Phoebe']
['Friend', 'Phoebe', 'Rachel']
['Exit']
```

Comment: Show the code....

Comment: It's somewhat long and a little spaghetti-ish but I can show it

Comment: Don't post long code, post the specific relevant code to demonstrate your problem.  If you don't know what that code is, keep trying until you do.  Please don't dump hundreds of lines of code on us and expect us to dig through it.

Comment: See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is that too long? ~130 lines

Comment: It's OK. Please also add the entire traceback for the error to your question.

Comment: Ok fixed it and added error traceback

Comment: You explicitly test for `peopleList.search(textList[2]) == None` a few lines later. Why are you surprised when you bind this expression to b and then find that b is None?

Comment: I think the problem is with the ' current ' local variable inside search() and remove() method. You are trying to return the local reference which will eventually get out of scope when the method returns. just try to make current as self.current once and see.

Comment: The problem is `peopleList.search()` returned `None`—not a user2 object—and it was assigned to `b`.

Comment: It is just an error check case as part of the assignment, but my problem occurs when a and b are both supposed to be legitimate objects, and they both are treated as NoneType

Comment: Ok it does seem to be what martineau said. Maybe I'm clueless, but I can't figure out why it isn't returning current.getData() inside search when it should be since the aforementioned objects I am attempting to search for and return exist already in the list

Comment: We're going to also need to see the `FriendData.txt` file's content. There's likely something wrong with the `UnorderedList` class or perhaps its `search()` method.

Comment: Ok I added the text file after it has been split into lists. I cut out the extraneous commands to shorten it

Comment: @user3491700 do you mind if I edit this question to make the code pythonic? You would learn a lot and others will be able to answer easily.

Comment: Sure, I don't mind at all

Answer (score 0):

From the code and the error message, it looks as if `textList[2]` is not in the `friendsList` attribute. In fact, it looks like it would not be; it looks like the only `User` in the `friendsList` attribute would be `textList[1]`, because `friendsList` is instantiated without any arguments, and only `textList[1]` is added afterwards.

Important to know: There are no pointers in Python. See here for more details: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=895804

Also important to know: The following is how to test if an object is `None` in Python:

```
if x is not None:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Apologies but which User's `friendsList` are you referring to? The `friendsList` structure is only supposed to hold the friends of each User as they are added, but I can't even seem to get that far because attempting to even access the `friendsList` structure in the a or b variable isn't working since they are seen as NoneType for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, on line 5 of your input, you try to add the friendship between Rachel and Ross, before the person Ross is added. The program can not find Ross, variable `b` is `None`, and b.getName() crashes.

Two things I noticed: in the search method of your User class, you need to return the result from the search. I also see that you are using getters and setters, which may be part of the assignment (?), but these are not needed in Python, as it has a milder form of encapsulation.

Comment: I scanned over the code due to suggestions in the comments and have come to realize it has something to do with the `search` method in `UnorderedList`. It isn't returning the `current.getData()` part and seems to skipping to the `return None` part because both a and b are returning as being NoneType

Comment: Are you sure it is not the input problem? I have downloaded your code and stepped through it in a debugger, and it worked fine with my custom input (as long as you add Persons before friendships between them).

Comment: Strangely I simply changed the `User` search method to return the result and it seems to work now fine, working with every line in the file. Very weird